# How can I solve this error \%RESOURCE_DIR%\?

Tags: installation, angular6, firebase-tools

**package.json Angular6:**

```
 {
          "name": "adnanrealestate",
          "version": "0.0.0",
          "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng serve",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e"
          },
          "private": true,
          "dependencies": {
            "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
            "@angular-mdc/web": "^0.36.3",
            "@angular/animation": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
            "@angular/animations": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
            "@angular/common": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/core": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/forms": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/http": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.7",
            "@angular/router": "^6.0.7",
            "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.16.1",
            "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
            "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
            "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.3",
            "@ngui/map": "^0.30.3",
            "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
            "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
            "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.10",
            "angular-captcha": "^3.4.0",
            "angular-file-upload": "^2.5.0",
            "angular-file-uploader": "^4.1.1",
            "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
            "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.12-next",
            "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
            "core-js": "^2.5.4",
            "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
            "filepond": "^1.8.6",
            "firebase": "^5.2.0",
            "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
            "firebase-functions": "^1.1.0",
            "firestore": "^1.1.6",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "fs": "0.0.1-security",
            "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
            "json2typescript": "^1.0.6",
            "linq2fire": "^1.0.18",
            "ng-bootstrap-form-validation": "^3.0.3",
            "ng-recaptcha": "^4.0.0",
            "ng-slideshow": "^0.8.2",
            "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
            "ngx-gallery": "^5.6.2",
            "ngx-international-phone-number": "^0.1.3",
            "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^1.0.6",
            "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.1",
            "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.0",
            "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
            "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
            "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
            "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
            "uikit": "^3.0.0-rc.6",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
            "@angular/cli": "^6.2.1",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.7",
            "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.7",
            "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
            "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
            "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
            "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
            "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
            "karma": "~1.7.1",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
            "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "protractor": "~5.3.0",
            "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
            "tslint": "~5.9.1",
            "typescript": "~2.7.2"
          }
```

**package.json firebase-functions**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[\%RESOURCE_DIR%\ image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNdGd.png)

How can I fix this error? 
and after a change to $ same error 
I use npm install for angular 6 and for firebase functions, I didn't see any difference.
please help this is a bad error I don't know where is error specifically of version or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610

I solved this problem, It's very easy. You don't need to uninstall.

**Step1**: open firebase.json
you will show this JSON file

```
"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
```

**Step2**: Delete `"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"`, and `"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"`

```
"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
   
    ]
  }
```

**Step3**: `firebase deploy --only functions.`